# Reflux connectFilter still sending updates to all listening components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs, datastore

I am using the [Reflux.connectFilter](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs#using-refluxconnectfilter) mixin to have a bunch of Graph components listen to changes in my GraphStore. Using the filter, they should only re-render when an element in the GraphStore's graphs array matching their ID is changed (or added/removed). However, when I update the a single element of the array, say by setting a name variable, I am still seeing all the listening Graphs re-render. Am I doing something wrong?

**GraphStore**

```
var Reflux       = require('reflux');
var GraphActions = require('./graphActions').GraphActions;

var GraphStore = Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [GraphActions],
  init: function() {
    this.graphs         = [];
    this.metricMetaData = {};
  },
  onAddGraph: function(graphId, name) { // Called only by the Dashboard component that is a parent to all Graphs
       this.graphs.push(
          {
             id:   graphId,
             name: ""
          }
       );

       this.updateGraphs();
  },
  onSetName: function(graphId, name) { // Called only by the Dashboard component that is a parent to all Graphs
     for(var i = 0, gl = this.graphs.length; i < gl; ++i) {
        if(this.graphs[i].id === graphId) {
           this.graphs[i].name = name;
           this.updateGraphs();
           return;
        }
     }
  },
  ...
  updateGraphs: function() {
    this.trigger(this.graphs); // This is the only place in the store where trigger is called
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return this.graphs;
  }
});

module.exports = {GraphStore: GraphStore};
```

**Graph**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React        = require('react');
var Reflux       = require('reflux');
var GraphActions = require('./graphActions').GraphActions;
var GraphStore   = require('./graphStore').GraphStore;

var Graph = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Reflux.connectFilter(GraphStore, "graph", function(graphs) {
    return graphs.filter(function(graph) {
      return graph.id === this.props.id;
    }.bind(this))[0];
  })],
  propTypes: {
    id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  ...
  render: function() {
    if(typeof this.state.graph === "undefined") {
       return (<div>The graph has not been created in the store yet</div>);
    } else {
       return (<div>Graph name: {this.state.graph.name}</div>);
    }
  }
};

module.exports = {Graph: Graph};
```

**Dashboard**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React        = require('react');
var Graph        = require('./graph').graph;
var GraphActions = require('./graphActions').GraphActions;
var UUID         = require('uuid');    

var Dashboard = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    numGraphs: React.PropTypes.int.isRequired
  },
  ...
  render: function() {
    var graphs = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.props.numGraphs; ++i) {
        var currId = UUID.v4();
        GraphActions.addGraph(currId, "");
        graphs.push(<Graph id={currId} />);
    }

    return (<div>{graphs}</div>);
  }
};

module.exports = {Dashboard: Dashboard};
```

Comment: The repo doesn't have `Reflux.connectFilter` anywhere mentioned

Comment: @AlxVallejo this question is almost three years old. I'm sure a lot has changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Reflux, but I think the issue here is that all your `Graph` instances are listening to the `GraphStore`, and as soon as that store sends an event, all component instances will receive that event. They will filter out the data they're not interested in, but Reflux will still call `setState` on all instances, triggering them to re-render. Reflux does not (to my knowledge) short-circuit re-renders if the result of the filter function is the same as it was before.

To short-circuit it and avoid re-rendering when you get the same data back, you need to implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` method on the component and compare the new state to the old state, and return false if it's the same.

A popular approach to this is to use [1] Immutable.js together with the [2] PureRenderMixin, which does the short-circuiting for you.

[1] https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js

[2] https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense about React.connectFilter. Thanks! Regarding the proposed solution: the two work well together? A note on the PureRender mixin states that it only does a shallow comparison, yet the Immutable.js objects seem like they can get pretty complex.

Comment: Well, the beauty of Immutable.js is that if you mutate a value deep down in the object, you get back a new reference to an object containing the change. So you can use a reference equality (===) check to see if two immutable objects are the same. When you mutate a plain JS object, you don't get a new reference so you have to do a deep compare, which you don't need with Immutable.js.

Comment: I've finally got it all rewritten in Immutable and I've implemented the PureRenderMixin ... works like a charm! Thanks again.